# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ora-00933

I try to run the follow:

```
select *
from tax.tax_payer@reis tp
left outer join re_right@reis r on (tp.tin = r.tin or tp.tin = r.tin_a1 or tp.tin = r.tin_a2)
where (r.right_status = -1 or r.right_status is null)
--and r.right_id is not null
and tp.je_id = 12;
```

but keep getting

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

If I remove the comment it works fine but why?

Comment: Why is this tagged `C#`? In what form is this query being executed? If it's being turned into an SQL string and then executed via a .NET object, it could be processing the comment incorrectly.

Comment: @user673647: How are you running this query?  Via SQL*Plus, SQLDeveloper, in code?

Comment: Answer to both of you: The `c#` tag indicates that he runs the code in C#.

Answer (score 6):

The above code works perfectly in SQL*Plus, with suitable definitions in the remote database connection.  There must be some confounding piece of software in your actual execution environment.

Try using the "in-line comment" form, instead of the "until end of line comment".  Stylistically there's no need for ";" at the end of SQL statements unless your execution environment needs them, or you are submitting a multi-line procedural block of code (which this is not).

```
select *
  from tax.tax_payer@reis tp
       left outer join 
       re_right@reis r 
       on (   tp.tin = r.tin 
           or tp.tin = r.tin_a1 
           or tp.tin = r.tin_a2
          )
 where (   r.right_status = -1 
        or r.right_status is null
       )
    and tp.je_id = 12
 /* and r.right_id is not null */
```

Also, you may want to move all of the computations into the remote database instead of pulling the data across the wire and doing the joins on your more-local database.  (Some more recent versions of Oracle will do this optimization for you.)

Comment: You can also use `nvl(r.right_status,-1)=-1` in place of the initial condition in the `where` clause.

Comment: You can also use `tp.tin in (r.tin, r.tin_a1, r.tin_a2)` for the `join ... on` clause.  The Oracle plan optimizer will do this for you when it sees the `(W = X or W = Y or W = Z)` pattern, but the human eye has a harder time interpreting it without comparing the expressions.  This also helps avoid cut-and-paste-and-typo introduced errors.

Comment: I prefer in-line comments as it avoids the risk of line breaks being trimmed out along the way (which means anything after the -- gets ignored).

Comment: +1 Gary: in-line comments are much nicer for the poor DBA who has to try to decode queries-sans-linebreaks when you don't know how much code was commented out with `--`

Answer (score 2):

In .NET, you can't have the trailing semi-colon on your query - it screws up the query.

Comment: Actually, skip that - if you said it works when you uncomment the line, then this isn't it. But it did used to happen to me in the past where queries wouldn't work with the semi-colon.